# Stylesheets not loading on Apache2.4 with PHP 5.6 on FastCGI

Tags: apache-2.4, http-headers, php-fastcgi

I have Googled my heart out looking for an answer to this but cannot find one! I know it seems like a Stack Overflow sort of question but I didn't have these problems before I ran it through fastCGI which makes me think it is server related.

I have followed this tutorial: https://gist.github.com/gmodarelli/5887778 to use PHPFarm to set a different version of PHP for a specific vhost file.

The vhost file is as follows:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.[site name]
    ServerAlias *.[site name]

    VirtualDocumentRoot /files/web/%1/public_html

</VirtualHost>

<Directory /files/web>

    AddHandler php-cgi .php
    Action php-cgi /cgi-bin-php/php-cgi-5.6.25

    <FilesMatch "\.php">
        SetHandler php-cgi
    </FilesMatch>

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I am trying to run Magento, something I have done many times before, but CSS is not being loaded and am getting the following in the dev console:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html
```

The response header for the file is:

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 06 Jan 2017 02:26:28 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
Server:Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.6.25
```

Request header:

```
Accept:text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-AU,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:magento_downloader_session... blah blah
Host:magento.[site name]
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://magento.[site name]/downloader/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
```

I have tried adding

```
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|ico|png)$ \ no-gzip dont-vary
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:exe|t?gz|zip|bz2|sit|rar)$ \no-gzip dont-vary
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.pdf$ no-gzip dont-vary

BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
```

But this didn't work.

I have tried setting

```
zlib.output_compression=Off
zlib.output_compression_level = -1
```

And

```
zlib.output_compression=On
zlib.output_compression_level = 6
```

in php.ini. No dice.

I have added `AddType text/css css` to the root htaccess file but, again, no luck.

I am running thin on Google search terms and patience! Can anyone help me with this please?

**UPDATE**

I have just tried setting all of the permissions to files: 664 and folders 775 but still not working.

**Another Update**

Just as a test i have commented out the lines

```
AddHandler php-cgi .php
Action php-cgi /cgi-bin-php/php-cgi-5.6.25

<FilesMatch "\.php">
    SetHandler php-cgi
</FilesMatch>
```

This fixed the issue but, obviously, stops using the version of PHP I need

Any help at all on this would be amazing. Please!

Comment: It looks like you are serving CSS via PHP, rather than as static files. Are you sure that is what you intended?

Comment: Definitely not. I am just looking into the `<FilesMatch> directive to see if there is anything wrong in there

Comment: Usually when that happens, your `DocumentRoot` is wrong.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The `DocumentRoot` is working all of the other files are being loaded. Do you see anything wrong with the VHost file above?

Comment: Come on guys. There has to be someone out there who can help with this!